# UIpageviwcontroller load only single view in landscape mode when first time load view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios5

i need help in `UIpageviewcontroller` for universal application. i add this functionality in my app it works fine but when i load `UIpageviewcontroller` first time in Landscape mode it shows only single view. My problem is if device is in Landscape mode it load only sigle view at first time. i think its because of declaration code of `UIpageviewcontroller`.

Code -:

```
self.Pagecontrol = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:style
 navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:options];



    self.Pagecontrol.delegate = self;

    self.Pagecontrol.dataSource = self;


    //Step 3:
    //Set the initial view controllers.

    PageCurlView *contentViewController = [[PageCurlView alloc] init];

       NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:contentViewController];
    // &&& i add single view controller at time of declaration.   

    CGRect pageViewRect = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+15, self.view.frame.origin.y+15, self.view.frame.size.width-45, self.view.frame.size.height-35);
    pageViewRect = CGRectInset(pageViewRect, 5.0, 20.0);
    self.Pagecontrol.view.frame = pageViewRect;


    [self.Pagecontrol setViewControllers:viewControllers
                               direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                                animated:NO
                              completion:nil];


    //Step 4:
    //ViewController containment steps
    //Add the pageViewController as the childViewController
    [self addChildViewController:self.Pagecontrol];

    //Add the view of the pageViewController to the current view


    [self.BaseScrollView addSubview:self.Pagecontrol.view];
    [self.view addSubview:self.BaseScrollView];

    [self.Pagecontrol.view bringSubviewToFront:self.BaseScrollView];


    [self.Pagecontrol didMoveToParentViewController:self];

    //Step 5:
    // set the pageViewController's frame as an inset rect.


    //Step 6:
    //Assign the gestureRecognizers property of our pageViewController to our view's gestureRecognizers property.

 self.Pagecontrol.view.gestureRecognizers = self.Pagecontrol.gestureRecognizers;
```

// any one help me to solve this issue.

i appreciate you help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**PVCViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ContentViewController.h"


@interface PVCViewController : UIViewController<UIPageViewControllerDataSource>
{
    UIPageViewController *pageController;
    NSArray *pageContent;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPageViewController *pageController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *pageContent;

@end
```

**PVCViewController.m**

```
#import "PVCViewController.h"

@interface PVCViewController ()

@end

@implementation PVCViewController
@synthesize pageController, pageContent;

- (void) createContentPages
{
    NSMutableArray *pageStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        NSString *contentString = [[NSString alloc]
                                   initWithFormat:@"<html><head></head><body><h1>Chapter %d</h1><p>This is the page %d of content displayed using UIPageViewController in iOS 5.</p></body></html>", i, i];
        [pageStrings addObject:contentString];
    }

    pageContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:pageStrings];

}

- (ContentViewController*)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageContent count] == 0) ||
        (index >= [self.pageContent count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    ContentViewController *dataViewController =
    [[ContentViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"ContentViewController" bundle:nil];
    dataViewController.dataObject =[self.pageContent objectAtIndex:index];
    return dataViewController;
}

-(NSUInteger)indexOfViewController:(ContentViewController *)viewController
{
    return [self.pageContent indexOfObject:viewController.dataObject];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:
(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                        (ContentViewController *)viewController];
    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:
(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
                        (ContentViewController *)viewController];
    if (index == NSNotFound) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;
    if (index == [self.pageContent count]) {
        return nil;
    }
    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self createContentPages];

    NSDictionary *options =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInteger:UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid]
                                forKey: UIPageViewControllerOptionSpineLocationKey];

    self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc]
                           initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
                           navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal
                           options: options];

    self.pageController.doubleSided=YES;

    pageController.dataSource = self;
    [[pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];


    NSArray *viewControllers =[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[self viewControllerAtIndex:0],[self viewControllerAtIndex:1],nil];

    [pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers
                             direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                              animated:NO
                            completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:pageController];
    [[self view] addSubview:[pageController view]];
    [pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

**ContentViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ContentViewController : UIViewController
{
    UIPageViewController *pageController;
    NSArray *pageContent;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id dataObject;
@end
```

**ContentViewController.m**

```
#import "ContentViewController.h"

@interface ContentViewController ()

@end

@implementation ContentViewController
@synthesize webView, dataObject;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [webView loadHTMLString:dataObject
                    baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@""]];
}

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Add WebView to contentViewController xib and connect outlet to webView in ContentViewController.h file.

That's it..

Here is output

[image]

Comment: but when i call this line for getting current index it give empty array error dont know why array is empty -:  [[self.Pagecontrol viewControllers] objectAtIndex:0]; if i set single controller it works fine

Comment: in you code i face error on this line     NSUInteger index = [self indexOfViewController:
        (contentViewController *)viewController];     on this line i got empty array of viewcontroller

Comment: wait few minutes I am giving a sample